# Extjs 4.2 Parameter in listeners function

Tags: events, extjs, controller, extjs4, controls

I've got problem with my controller

```
Ext.define('app.controller.myController', {
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#myinputfield': {
                change: this.textFieldChange(parameter)
            }
        })
    },
    textFieldChange: function(parameter) {
      //do something
    }
});
```

its look like this
the problem is when i give parameter here

```
change: this.textFieldChange(parameter)
```

then its fire up after site load and I don't know why.

without parameter its waiting for change event like it should
can any1 help me please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because:

`change: this.textFieldChange` here you are giving the reference for this function to this property

`change: this.textFieldChange(parameter)` here you are giving the **result** of the function to this property (which if we don't use return, then it will be `undefined`).

You can use the `eOpts` variable in the function definition, for custom parameter sending, see in Example:

```js
Ext.define('app.controller.myController', {
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#myinputfield': {
                change: {
                    fn : this.textFieldChange,
                    params : {
                        param1: 'something'
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    },
    textFieldChange: function(textfield, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        var params = eOpts.params;
        console.log(params.param1);
      //do something
    }
});
```